# Does Chrome allow auto discovery of OpenSearch?

Tags: google-chrome, opensearch

Our company has an internal website that I am trying to add Chrome Omnibox support for via OpenSearch.  The site is built with ASP.NET MVC 5.
I have added the following line to the `<head>` tag of my layout page:
`<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="ABC" href="/abcopensearch.xml" />`

Here is my xml document which lives at the root level and is named `abcopensearch.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>ABC</ShortName>
  <Description>Find all your assets</Description>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://www.abcstaff.com/Abc?q={searchTerms}"/>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

What am I missing? Did Chrome remove the ability to automatically add search engines?  I've restarted Chrome several times.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/tab-to-search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650377/opensearch-description-document-discovery-and-chrome

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that article, which is fairly old in Chrome years.  Since none of their ideas of worked, I was wondering if Chrome had changed it's policies.

Comment: Does https://www.abcstaff.com/Abc?q={searchTerms} actually return any search terms results?

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome [no longer supports the autodiscovery of site specific search](https://twitter.com/googlechrome/status/1504858912692084745)

> @googlechrome twitter account: 
> We made it so new Site search shortcuts are no longer automatically added to the Chrome search bar. We did this to help avoid cluttering it with Site search suggestions that people may not be using.

Comment: Personally, I think they did this because site specific search made it easier for users to bypass using Google Search. Without site specific search, users probably end up using Google Search more (assuming the have Google Chrome's omnibar configured to use Google Search).